# Python 3.9.6 - subprocess.run - subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command pip install pkg returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, subprocess

Python 3.9.6 - subprocess.run - subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/disk1/apps/venv_test/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install pkg', '-q']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Using Python 3.9.6, unable to get the below code executed and its throwing error for --pkg-- package. Error is given at below.

However, when trying to run the same command manually on linux console

```
command -> /opt/disk1/apps/venv_test/bin/python -m pip install pkg -q
```

then

- this manual execution completed successfully
- --pkg-- package got installed as well and
- **after this manual execution, when trying to execute below piece of code then its not throwing this or any other error as well**

*Please advice why the code is not able to get executed without installing pkg manually?

Let me know if any additional info is required along with way to get this please.*

Code giving this error ->

```
  packages = ['fileinput', 'glob', 'gzip', 'hashlib', 'json', 'paramiko', 'pkg', 'psutil', 're', 'requests',
              'shutil',
              'socket']
  [subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install ' + pckg, '-q'], check=True) for pckg in packages if
   not importlib.util.find_spec(pckg)]
```

Error: -

```
ERROR: unknown command "install pkg" - maybe you meant "install"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/disk1/apps/bookcomponents.py", line 653, in <module>
    get_configurations_and_extract_info(redownload=False, kill_restart_required=True,
  File "/opt/disk1/apps/bookcomponents.py", line 504, in get_configurations_and_extract_info
    [subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install ' + pckg, '-q'], check=True) for pckg in packages if
  File "/opt/disk1/apps/bookcomponents.py", line 504, in <listcomp>
    [subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install ' + pckg, '-q'], check=True) for pckg in packages if
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/disk1/apps/venv_test/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install pkg', '-q']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
(venv_test) [login@server:/opt/disk1/apps/Book/05Aug2022]$  pip list | grep pkg
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/disk1/apps/venv_test/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(venv_test) [login@server:/opt/disk1/apps/Book/05Aug2022]$  python --version
Python 3.9.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't concatenate the package name with the `install` keyword. You're executing

```
php -m pip 'install fileinput' -q
```

instead of

```
php -m pip install fileinput -q
```

`install` and `pckg` should be separate arguments, not a single concatenated string.

```
  [subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', pckg, '-q'], check=True) for pckg in packages if
    not importlib.util.find_spec(pckg)]
```

BTW, it's not pythonic to use a list comprehension if you're not doing anything with the resulting list. Use an ordinary `for` loop.

```
for pck in packages:
    if not importlib.util.find_spec(pckg):
        subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', pckg, '-q'], check=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar .... Could you please advice why the +pckg command not throwing mentioned error after manual pip install?

Comment: It's the difference between `pip install pkg` and `pip 'install pkg'`. You're combining them into a single argument.

Comment: Agree @Barmar .... and after replacing +pckg with , pckg, it stopped throwing this error. 

However, the question is why the +pckg command throwing error before pkg package is not installed manually and after that it is not throwing mentioned error. As i executed the +pckg command only before and after manual installation and before its throwing the error and after manual execution of pip install for --pkg why and how it started working.

Comment: I don't know. When it threw the error, it should also have printed an error message, maybe that will have a clue.

Comment: please advice with an example @Barmar for your comment -> BTW, it's not pythonic to use a list comprehension if you're not doing anything with the resulting list. Use an ordinary for loop.

Comment: I've added the `for` loop version.